# Nest JS Dependencies

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, backend, nestjs-typeorm

I am trying to use the UserRepository class on the UserService class and export the UserService from the UserModule so I can use that class on the AuthService class but I am getting some errors mentioning the UserRepository...

User Module

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]), ProfileModule, CartModule],
  providers: [UserService, UserRepository],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

User Repository

```
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private readonly _userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}}
```

User Service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly _userRepository: UserRepository,
    private readonly _profileService: ProfileService,
    private readonly _cartService: CartService,
  ) {}}
```

Auth Service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly _userService: UserService,
    private readonly _jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}}
```

Auth Module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: '********',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '6h',
      },
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [JwtStrategy, PassportModule],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Error I'm getting

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, JwtService). Please make sure that the argument "UserRepository" at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If "UserRepository" is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If "UserRepository" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing "UserRepository" */ ]
  })
```

I created a class for the database interactions: UserRepository class, a class for the business logic: UserService, and i would use that service on the AuthService

Comment: Why are you using `@InjectRepository(User)` in the `AuthService` for the `UserService` provider?